# AMP page showing invalid when visiting with Chrome despite showing valid when checking with validator.ampproject.org

Tags: amp-html, simple-machines-forum

The pages validate via https://validator.ampproject.org and https://search.google.com/test/amp but when I access them with my Android phone or a mobile phone emulator via desktop (Chrome browser), I get "Sorry this page is not valid amp html" and get redirected to the forum's home page. When I try with any other browser (via the phone), I see the amp page. When I try with Firefox (desktop), then error is displayed again and redirected to home page.

To replicate the issue, use Chrome from a phone and search for **pre-owned translatum**, it will bring up an amp page. Click on that and see what happens. Please see a screen recording of the process here:  https://www.translatum.gr/downloads/mobile.mp4

Example pages:
https://www.translatum.gr/forum/index.php?action=amp;topic=987010

https://www.translatum.gr/forum/index.php?action=amp;topic=985701.0

[image: amp error]

Comment: Strange. Suggest that you open an issue on https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues. You also might present the issue on AMP Slack https://amphtml.slack.com/ with a link to the GitHub issue. Folks with these types of issues usually get quick assistance.

Comment: This is the reply I got: Use & instead of ; for different query params.  Update the server for this domain to handle escaped query params for %3B (which is ;).

https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/31063#issuecomment-725607708

Not sure really how to implement that.

Comment: `honeybadgerdontcare` is an expert; i see his point. Instead of using the keyboard char, use the HTML escape code (as recommended in the GitHub issue). My advice is to use one of the services to properly format safe URLs. I use https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/ Also, use hex values as they have the same root as used for Unicode. Then you can easily toggle the safe URL for either HTML or for JSON.

Comment: The advice I can see, correct me if I am wrong, is to use & instead of ; as URL parameter separator (but = also appears to get an entity there). The escape code displayed on search results URL is what apparently is causing the issue. My point is that canonical URLs have the same separators without such an issue. The URL-creating bit I can access is `'?action=amp;topic=' . $topic .'">'` according to the advice this should be the way to go `'?action=amp?topic=' . $topic .'">'` which leaves the = signs unaccounted for.